# Firebase : Send Country Specific Push

Tags: objective-c, firebase

**Requirement :**
I want to associate FCM device token with country, so that i can target users country wise while sending push.

**Study:**
I have read about the `Topic Messaging on iOS` under Firebase docs,
there i found out that we can add country as a topic and then can send push accordingly.

**Issue:**
My app is based on location, so i want my country to decided on the basis of coordinates rather than hardcoding it using Country Code or Country Name.

**Ref:**
https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/ios/topic-messaging

Comment: Get country name of user with FCM token. Then ask your backend guy to send push notification according to that.

Comment: @himanth can you please let me know how to get country name of user along with FCM token. As i am new in IOS, I am not having that much knowledge .

Comment: May be you can't get country code your self. Ask user when app launches and then save it. So whenever you are pushing fcm token to your server team then push that country code also